# Certain Files Read-Only on a Samba Share

Tags: permissions, samba, minecraft

I'm running a Ubuntu 19.10 Server VM so I can play Minecraft with my friends.
I setup Samba so I could easily edit config files and add things and remove them.

Recently if a plugin creates config files, I can read the files, but whenever I try to save or delete these files, they give me an error that I need permission to delete or save these files, or they are read-only.

Here is the smb.conf

```
[minecraft]
   comment = Minecraft server files.
   path = /home/minecraft
   create mask = 0770
   directory mask = 0770
   writeable = yes
   valid users = @minecraft
   force user = minecraft
   force group = minecraft
```

I was told it was an issue with Samba not forcing the permissions.